# Redirect with Htaccess - Calendar Pagination

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, calendar

my calendar pagination like this

```
example.com/calendar/2014/page/2
example.com/calendar/2014/04/page/2
example.com/calendar/2014/04/05/page/2
```

someone go to `/page/` without last number i want to redirect for without `/page/` ... i want like this type.. if can someone help me for this one.

```
Note : i want 301 redirect
```

i want to redirect like this

> example.com/calendar/2014/page/ (with slash or without slash) -> example.com/calendar/2014
>
> example.com/calendar/2014/04/page/ (with slash or without slash) -> example.com/calendar/2014/04
>
> example.com/calendar/2014/04/05/page/ (with slash or without slash) -> example.com/calendar/2014/04/05

here is my code htaccess

/calendar/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /calendar/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(page)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&p=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(page)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&p=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&date=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(page)/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?year=$1&month=$2&date=$3&p=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this 301 rule just below your existing 1st `www` enforcing 301 rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)/page/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: but its after redirect have slash :(

Comment: end it from slash.. i want without slash

Comment: and this link also want redirect /page

Comment: no its after redirect i want like this only.. example.com/calendar/2014 (dont want slash)

Comment: Above rule will redirect `http://example.com/calendar/2014/page` to `http://example.com/calendar/2014` is that not you want?

Comment: yeah but its finished from /calendar/2014/ i want without last slash after redirect

Comment: now this also redierct example.com/calendar/2014/page/2 :(